# Download a zip, extract the CSV and parse it - All in memory - Java

Tags: java, apache, csv, zip

I have a URL with a .zip file that contains .CSV files.

I am writing an application in Java that needs to download this .zip file and access the CSV files inside the .zip and parse them in a List of CSVRecords using Apache Commons CSV. I don't want to have to write any file to disk, as this is a performance waste.

This is what I have so far (I omitted all error handling for now, it's just a POC):

```
URL url = new URL(myURLString);
InputStream input = url.openStream();
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(input);
ZipEntry entry;
while((entry = zipIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(zipIn);
    CSVParser csv = new CSVParser(isr, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
    List<CSVRecord> records = csv.getRecords(); <----- THIS IS WHERE IT HANGS!
}
```

For some reason, I can't figure out why it hangs when the CSVParser tries to read the files. Any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S.: I can read a CSV just fine when it is not in a zip, as such:

```
URL url = new URL(myURLString);
InputStream input = url.openStream();
InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(input );
CSVParser csv = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
List<CSVRecord> records = csv.getRecords();
```

Comment: can u try CSVFormat.Excel and let me know what happens ?

Comment: It just hangs there, doesn't return anything

Comment: Can you ensure that the contents of the zip file are correct and it has all files with .csv extensions only

Comment: Yes, the zip file is fine, I can download it manually from a browser and extract the CSV and open them just fine.

Comment: Actually, the loop finds the CSV files, it's just that the CSVParser can't seem to be able to access them through the Stream

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using a different parser. Using [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) will likely report any error processing your files.

Just change to:

```
URL url = new URL(myURLString);
InputStream input = url.openStream();
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(input);
ZipEntry entry;
//configure the parser to detect the CSV format automatically
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.detectFormatAutomatically();
//use this if the files are small (less than 50mb each)
//parserSettings.setReadInputOnSeparateThread(false);

CsvParser csv = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

while((entry = zipIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(zipIn);
    List<Record> records = csv.parseAllRecords(isr);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this libary. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library [unzip-csv](https://github.com/skjolber/unzip-csv) which supports your use-case. It can even unzip specific files within the archive (downloading segments), and also supports multithreaded workers.